# OTRS cannot get emails from MS Exchange server

Tags: exchange-server, otrs

I configured OTRS for getting emails from Exchange
But I get an error :

```
Backend ERROR: OTRS-CGI-59 Perl: 5.10.1 OS: linux Time: Tue Apr 15 18:01:56 2014

Message: IMAP: Auth for user user/domain.local failed! RemoteAddress: 192.168.176.33 RequestURI: /otrs/index.pl?Action=AdminMailAccount;Subaction=Run;ID=1;ChallengeToken=0KoFVsy4z8DHo2IDkWWbdegGhIZyizZT; 
Traceback (1635): Module: Kernel::System::MailAccount::IMAP::_Fetch (OTRS 3.3.6) Line: 124
  Module: Kernel::System::MailAccount::IMAP::Fetch (OTRS 3.3.6) Line: 77
  Module: Kernel::System::MailAccount::MailAccountFetch (OTRS 3.3.6) Line: 427
  Module: Kernel::Modules::AdminMailAccount::Run (OTRS 3.3.6) Line: 64
  Module: Kernel::System::Web::InterfaceAgent::Run (OTRS 3.3.6) Line: 871
  Module: ModPerl::ROOT::ModPerl::Registry::opt_otrs_bin_cgi_2dbin_index_2epl::handler (unknown version) Line: 41 Module: (eval) (v1.99) Line: 204
  Module: ModPerl::RegistryCooker::run (v1.99) Line: 204
  Module: ModPerl::RegistryCooker::default_handler (v1.99) Line: 170
  Module: ModPerl::Registry::handler (v1.99) Line: 31
```

I don't have access to a Exchange sever. How to deal with it.

Comment: Could you please show us the configuration file?

Comment: There are few config files such as Config.pm, ZZZAuto.pm, ZZZAAuto.pm.

Comment: What kind of them I should provide as they are too long ?
In additional, I have tried to connect to a gmail account (as described here http://wiki.otterhub.org/index.php?title=Configure_OTRS_with_Gmail) but issue is same.However in the log appears an IP "RemoteAddress: 192.168.176.33". I think there should be a google IP, isn't it?. Nevertheless PC has access to the Internet.

Comment: by the way:  # telnet imap.gmail.com 993
Trying 74.125.143.109...
Connected to imap.gmail.com.
Escape character is '^]'.
That excludes a network issues

Answer (score 0):

I get success with fetching mail from gmail.

So, my settings for gmail are:

```
 menu like Administrators->email accounts for PostMaster:
    Type: POP3S    (it means gmail use port 995)
    login: bla-bla
     password:****
    server: pop.gmail.com
```

then actually I'm not sure, it need to read the manual

```
 trusted: yes
 redirect: ..by selected queue
 actuality: actual
```

---

It confirmed that system fetch mail, than I will discuss with a Exchange administrator.